# How to trigger collection's method from a model method with a current model as a parameter

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following setup:

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model;
var chapters = new Backbone.Collection;

chapters.add(new Chapter({index: 9, title: "The End"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({index: 5, title: "The Middle"}));
chapters.add(new Chapter({index: 1, title: "The Beginning"}));
```

On request I need to change index of chapters. Is there any way for me to implement method `changeIndexes` on the `Chapters` collection with the following syntax:

```
var Chapters = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  changeIndexes: function(model, bool: increase) {
    // change indexes of the model and sibling models here
  }
});
```

and methods `increase` and `decrease` on the model from collections:

```
var Chapter = Backbone.Model.extend({
   increase: function() {},
   decrease: function() {}
);
```

and have method `changeIndexes` triggered with model and `increase=true` whenever a `modelFromCollection.increse()` is triggered, and with `increase=false` whenever a `modelFromCollection.decrease()` is triggered?

My first guess is to use custom events propagated within a collection. Is this a way to go or maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: You can directly update the model. Why do you need a collection method to do it?

Comment: because collection need to update other models as a result of updating the current one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call changeIndexes from the model's function, the collection can be directly referenced.

```
var Chapter  = Backbone.Model.extend({
    increase: function(){
        this.collection.changeIndexes(this, true);
    },
    decrease: function(){
        this.collection.changeIndexes(this, false);
    },
});
```

Alternatively, the collection can listen to the change event on the models.

```
var Chapters = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(){
      this.on('change:index', this.changeIndexes_2);
  },
  changeIndexes_2: function(model, attrValue) {
      // do something
  }
});
```